# JUnit testing Spymemcached client

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, spymemcached

I have a class which wraps around spymemcached client and I would like to write some JUnit tests to test if the getValue and addKey methods work or not.

The problem is that the spymemcached server is not reachable from the test server so I guess some mocking is required here.

My simplified class looks something like this:

```
public class SpyMemcachedClientWrapper {

    private MemcachedClient spyMemcachedClient;

    public SpyMemcachedClientWrapper()
        spyMemcachedClient = new MemcachedClient(new ConnectionFactoryBuilder().build(),
                        AddrUtil.getAddresses("192.168.1.122:11211"));
    }

    public Object getValue(Object key) {
        Object obj = null;
        Future<Object> f = null;

        f = spyMemcachedClient.asyncGet(key);

        try {
            obj = f.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            f.cancel(false);
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public boolean addKey(Object key, Object value) {
        OperationFuture<Boolean> t = spyMemcachedClient.set(key, 0, value);
        return t.getStatus().isSuccess();
    }
}
```

Can you please give me some hints or best practice advise how can I write the SpyMemcachedClientWrapperTest for this class? I am thinking that I could use Mockito or EasyMock (Mockito is preferable but if EasyMock is better here, thats fine also) but so far I could not figure out what's the usually preferred way here to write the tests in this scenario.

An example  would be appreciated also.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're asking yourself the wrong question. What are you trying to test? These are ordered from least to most likely.

- Are you trying to test that the `SpyMemcached` library works properly?

  - If that's true, you shouldn't be testing your wrapper.
- Are you trying to test that your classes call the proper methods of `SpyMemcachedClientWrapper`?

  - If that's true, you should be testing the other classes, and providing a mock of `SpyMemcachedClientWrapper`.
- Are you trying to test that `SpyMemcachedClientWrapper` calls the correct methods of `MemcachedClient` in various scenarios?

First of all, the reason you are struggling to test this is that you are calling `new` inside the constructor of your wrapper. This is where dependency injection comes into play. In other words, the main conclusion to take away from this answer is:

### You don't actually need `SpyMemcached` to test this behavior.

The behavior has nothing to do with `SpyMemcached`! All you need is the interface. However, because you call `new` in the constructor, you can't actually get at this code to provide, say, a mock of `MemcachedClient`. [**This article is an absolute, must read for you.**](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/)

However, I will briefly sum up the conclusions from that article, and how they apply to your situation. You can either:

1. **Not preferred** [Use PowerMock to override the behavior of the `new` operator](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor). This way you can replace the creation of the `MemcachedClient` object with a mock and call `verify` methods on it.
2. **Preferred** Refactor your constructor to use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and then simply pass a mock to the wrapper in the constructor. This will allow you to call `verify` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to check whether your wrapper calls the correct methods, you'd rather like to know if the spymemcached library works as expected when calling out to a real memcached.

If that's the case, you don't want to write a unit test, you want to write an integration test, because a unit test is by definition a test without any external resources.

And if the real memcache server is not reachable from the server where the tests run, why not fire up a test memcache and configure the test run I.e. with a property file with what host to connect.

As durron in the previous answer said it clearly would help to refactor the hard coded constructor to accept a spymemcached instance which you then can further influence I.e. for unit testing/mocking.

As a side note: a quick and dirty solution would be to replace the hard coded connection string with a call to System.getProperty and then setting the variable with -D... when starting the test run, but as I said, that's quick and dirty ;-)