# Is there a way to set up and tear down a local memcached instance at runtime?

Tags: java, unit-testing, memcached

Is there a way to set up and tear down a local memcached instance at runtime? For context, this would be required in order to build unit tests for a component that uses memcached--the unit tests would need to set up and tear down the memcached instance and connect to it via localhost

I'd prefer not to use Powermock or Mockito as a solution, as this would create too much coupling between the unit test and the underlying implementation/framework chosen to implement the memcached wrapper under test. In my mind a better quality test would simply manage a runtime instance of memcached and verify that expected data has been inserted/updated/removed after calling the wrapper's methods, remaining agnostic to the underlying implementation of the wrapper.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149755/junit-testing-spymemcached-client

Comment: Mocking the memcached client interface and not using an actual memcached instance at all for unit tests is the best solution, based on the information you've given.

Comment: @tgdavies see my update. I'm looking to do something similar to setting up and tearing down a HyperSQL instance in order to test an SQL wrapper. In my mind, having the unit test mock the underlying client interface creates too much coupling with the wrapper under test. I'd rather the wrapper be a black box to the unit tests

Comment: I think it's simpler to mock the client interface. Particularly dealing with Future, you will want to be able to control exactly how they complete in your tests, which I don't think you can do with a real memcached client.

Comment: @tgdavies I think I'll go ahead with that solution for now but I'll still keep this up in case anyone has an answer